# How to send Service Extras through ADB [null extras received]

Tags: android, adb

I have tried to use this command : `adb shell am startservice com.bytel.velizy.automation/.ExchangeService -es "begin" "lol" -es  "priority" "hjhjhj"`
but it's seems that my Android app doesn't receive Extras "begin" and "priority"

I have these lines in my service ExchangeService :

```
    if(intent.hasExtra("begin") && intent.hasExtra("priority")){
        Log.i("AUTOMATION_ADB" , "EXTRAS : " + intent.getStringExtra("begin") + " " + intent.getStringExtra("priority") );
    }else{
        Log.i("AUTOMATION_ADB" , "NOTHING" );
    }
```

I get the "Nothing" in the logcat;

in the cmd command I have this message :

```
Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.bytel.velizy.automation/.ExchangeService launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }
```

How can I pass Extras using ADB for startservice ?

Comment: from the help: `[-e|--es <EXTRA_KEY> <EXTRA_STRING_VALUE> ...]` - did you try `-e` or `--es` ?

Comment: I have tried this 'adb shell am startservice com.bytel.velizy.automation/.ExchangeService --es "begin" "lol" --es  "priority" "hjhjhj"'

Is it that or I misunderstood?
'Starting service: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.bytel.velizy.automation/.ExchangeService launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }'

Comment: yes, `--es` is ok

Comment: I have still the "Nothing" in my logcat

Comment: try `adb shell am startservice --es begin end --es priority nopriority com.bytel.velizy.automation/.ExchangeService`

Comment: I have forgotten the **-n** 
And the correct command is : **adb shell am startservice -n com.bytel.velizy.automation/.ExchangeService --es begin lol --es priority oiii**
I get in the cmd 
**Starting service: Intent { cmp=com.bytel.velizy.automation/.ExchangeService launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mBaseDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) }**

Your command works as well ! 
Thanks for you help :)

Comment: you dont need **-n** (see my prev comment)

Comment: Thank you very much @pskink !

Comment: sure, your welcome